# How to implement my median method into the quicksort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, pseudocode

I have the method Median(int[] numbers), which returns the median of the array. Now i want to implement this method into [the quicksort algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDGQS.png), so that the runtime of quicksort is always O(log(n)). After a few attemps i thought that this must be the solution:

```
/**
     * Sorts an array with the quicksort algorithm.
     * 
     * @param numbers the array to sort.
     * @param l       the left index of the sorted range.
     * @param r       the right index of the sorted range.
     * @return the sorted array.
     */
    public static int[] quicksort(int[] numbers, int l, int r) {
        quicksortArray = numbers;

        int x;
        int temp;
        int i;
        int j;

        if (l < r) {

            int[] arrayForMedian = Arrays.copyOfRange(quicksortArray, l, r);
            x = lowerMedian(arrayForMedian);
            i = l + 1;
            j = r;

            while (i <= j) {
                while ((i <= j) && (quicksortArray[i] <= x)) {
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                while ((i <= j) && (quicksortArray[j] >= x)) {
                    j = j - 1;
                }

                if (i < j) {
                    temp = quicksortArray[i];
                    quicksortArray[i] = quicksortArray[j];
                    quicksortArray[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            i = i - 1;
            quicksortArray[l] = quicksortArray[i];
            quicksortArray[i] = x;
            quicksort(quicksortArray, l, i - 1);
            quicksort(quicksortArray, i + 1, r);
        }
        return quicksortArray;
    }
```

But for some reason it doesn't work, e.g. when i have {10,1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5} as input it returns [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9], so it kinda overwrite values which should not be overwritten. Does anybody has a solution for me how to fix that code? i appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: This will significantly slow down your Quicksort. For guaranteed worst case, prefer Heapsort.

Comment: i have the task to implement the median as pivot into quicksort, so i i have to do that^^

Comment: Did I miss something? For my understanding the calculation of the median requires to sort the set of values. How could then the median speed up a sorting algorithm?

Comment: Regarding the code there is at least the problem that you do not partition the first element with `i = l + 1` and later simply overwrite it with `quicksortArray[l] = quicksortArray[i];`. This means that the first element will always get lost and the pivot will be duplicated (exception is when median is at first place by chance). In order to make it work you would have to keep track of the median index to swap it to the middle correctly.

Comment: Regarding the runtime, I think the other comments are correct. Calculating the median takes O(n log n) itself. Could it be that your assignment only states that the pivot should be the middle value? This would make sense as you can pick the middle value in O(1) and it is a [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) partition schema.

Comment: @tquadrat: no, finding the median dos not require a sort. It is well known that it can be done in worst-case linear-time O(n).